# Heisenberg Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras

Dear forum,

I would like to ask if $H(m)$ is the Heisenberg Lie algebra of dimension $2m+1$ and $M$ is an ideal of $H(m)$. Can we say that $M$ has a complement in $H(m)$?

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "complement" here?   What happens when you take `$M$` to be the 1-dimensional center?

Comment: Hint: what happens if $M$ is the centre of $H(m)$? 

Comment: If $M\neq 0$, then I guess $H(m)/M$ is a free Lie algebra and so
$0\rightarrow M\rightarrow H(m)\rightarrow H(m)/M\rightarrow 0$ is split so the result follows.

Comment: In fact, I think $H(m)/M$  is abelian Lie algebra.

Comment: But Im not sure in this way!!!


Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, if $M$ would have a complement, then the exact sequence
$$
0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow H(m)\rightarrow H(m)/M \rightarrow 0
$$
would be split. But this is not true in general. If it were true for
$M=Z(H(m))$, then $H(m)$ were abelian ($M$ and $H(m)/M$ abelian), a contradiction.

For an answer to a similar question, see [Lie algebras and complements](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31679/lie-algebras-and-complements).